# Need Recommendation for Database Hosting

Tags: mysql, database, hosting

I need a recommendation for hosting solution. I have developed a android app which have about 5K to 10K users per day. They will do different type of transactions on MySql database. Now, my questions are below:

1.) Which type of hosting should i choose (Shared, Dedicated, VPS or Cloud)

2.) Recommend any Preferable Hosting Solution for my Requirement.

Will Shared Hosting is enough to support my requirements?

Comment: I would use Amazon Web Services RDS, where you can start with an RDS instance and you can grow it as long as you get more users.

Answer (score 0):

I am too an android developer therefore i can understand your pain. I can recommend from my experience. 
Shared hosting is also enough if the server load balancing is great else VPS would do
I use hostgator hosting so that is enough for me but i have google and aws on backup. 
I would recommend to start with firebase because its free for initial use and if your app grows then you can upgrade the plan and in this way you will be saved from hosting issues and managing it. All work will reside in firebase and its great for analytics,crash reporting and mobile testing.